# How to sort a list of integer without built-in function and let-in expression in Haskell?

Tags: sorting, haskell

I have this code that output the sorted list of integer. If i want to change my code by removing the let-in expression but still want the same output, what should I do?

```
sort :: [Int] -> [Int]
sort [] = []
sort li =
    let 
        small = sort [a | a <- tail li, a <= head li]
        big = sort [a | a <- tail li, a > head li]
    in small ++ [head li] ++ big
```

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell you can just substitute equals for equals in an expression, and the expression's value won't change.

In particular, if you have `a = b` in some expression `...a...`, you can just put `b` wherever `a` was in that expression, getting `...b...`, and the expression's value won't change:

```
    let  small = sort [a | a <- tail li, a <= head li]
         big   = sort [a | a <- tail li, a >  head li]
    in 
       small ++ [head li] ++ big
```

becomes

```
       ..... ++ [head li] ++ .....
```